# Epimorphisms of schemes

Tags: category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Assume we have a morphism of schemes between two affine schemes. Is it true that it is an epimorphism in the category of schemes iff it is an epimorphism in the full subcategory of affine schemes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the two different inclusions of the affine line in the affine line with doubled origin, precomposed by the (very affine) inclusion of the affine line *without the origin* in the affine line.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. The inclusion $A[X] → A[X]_X$ is mono in the category of commutative rings, so for $U =  \operatorname{Spec} A[X]_X$, the inclusion $ι \colon U → \mathbb A^1_A$ is epi in the category of *affine* schemes, but for the affine line over $A$ with doubled origin $Z_A$, the two different inclusions $j \colon \mathbb A^1_A → Z_A$ and $k \colon \mathbb A^1_A → Z_A$ give both the same composition $jι = kι$, so $ι$ is *not* epi in the category of schemes.

Comment: is it necessarily an epimorphism in the category of separated schemes?

Comment: @A.Smith I’m sorry, I don’t know and I lack the intuition to assess this. (My guess would be that it is, but you really shouldn’t ascribe any value to this.)